# When a React element is returned from a component, is just one React.createElement() called on the top-level tag?

Tags: reactjs, tags, element, createelement

Please correct me if I'm wrong about any of this.

A component returns a React element/object.

It does so by running React.createElement().

With JSX, it implicitly does this.

You could also write it without JSX and just use the React.createElement() code explicitly.

But I'm trying to figure out if the returned element/object calls React.createElement() on just a single top-level tag within the component's return code.

Or if it calls React.createElement() on the top-level parent tag AND on each of its children.

Ultimately, either way, I'm assuming the returned element/object is put inside the returned element/object of the parent component.

But what exactly is happening underneath when you have multiple tags in the return of the component? Multiple React.createElement() calls? Or just one?

Because in the React docs, the two examples I could find both just have a single tag and is exemplifying an explicit element return with this code:

```
  const element = React.createElement(
    "h1",
    { className: "greeting" },
    "Hello, world!"
  );
```

// Equivalent to

```
  const element = (
        // JSX
    <h1 className="greeting">
        Hello, world!
    </h1>
  );
```

// And just returning element

// Versus returning an element/object with multiple tags

```
 const element = (
        // JSX
   <div>
     <h1 className="greeting">
        Hello, world!
     </h1>
     <p> lalalalala </p>
   </div>
  );
```

// Are there now multiple React.createElement() calls on all three tags? Or just the top-level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is how your last example translated by babel**

```
var element = // JSX
React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement("h1", {
  className: "greeting"
}, "Hello, world!"), React.createElement("p", null, " lalalalala "));
```

Comment: use https://babeljs.io/repl this url to check how your jsx code translated

Comment: Ah, thanks, Dostonbek. I was looking at this for quite a while. So it's just kind of nesting all these React.createElement()s. Very useful site too.